# How to run a command after the pod is in running status?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with multiple int containers and one main container. I need to run a command on the main container when it's in Running status. I've tried `lifecycle postStart` as below but this doesn't wait for the container to be in running status:

```
lifecycle:
    postStart:
       exec:
         command: ["bash", "-c", "{{ command }}"]
```

Is there a way to run the command after the main container or pod is in running status?

Comment: Can you say a little more about your use case?  If this weren't in a container, how would you run this command inside this process?  Would it make sense to launch this as a separate Job?

Comment: You could try to get a Shell to run commands inside the Container like in the following example:
`kubectl exec --stdin --tty your_pod_name -- /bin/bash`
In this example, the command will execute an interactive bash shell on the container, and then you can run commands inside the container.
Also, you can use this flag --container or -c to specify a container in the kubectl exec if you are running more than one container. In this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-application/get-shell-running-container/), you can find more information about it .

Answer (score 0):

try to use this sintax,

```
          args:
            - bash
            - -c {{ command }}
```